# How to use D3.js file in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, reports-api

HI could anyone please say how to use d3.js step by step procedure with small example from the scrtch like loading the script in static resuorces will be so thank full to you in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Below is a Visualforce page that uses D3 to draw some text.

This assumes that you have taken "d3.min.js", put it in a folder called "lib", zipped that folder, and added the resulting ZIP file as a static resource called "d3zip". Consult the salesforce help for how to add a static resource.

```
<apex:page>

Before D3
<div id="my-d3"/>
After D3

<script src="{!URLFor($Resource.d3zip, 'lib/d3.min.js')}"></script>
<script>
// Data to draw   
var data = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'];

// Drawing will be done in an SVG element
var svg = d3.select("div#my-d3").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 400)
        .attr("height", 350)
        .attr("class", "svg");

// Draw each piece of data
svg.selectAll().data(data).enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return 20 + i * 50;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            return 20 + i * 50
        })
        .attr("font-size", function (d, i) {
            return 10 + i * 10;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });
</script>
</apex:page>
```

The output is:

[image: sample output]